# fitting 2D_gaussian on image to extract the covariance matrix in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, gaussian, template-matching

I used the cv2 for template matching with the following code:

```
result = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

Then, I used a [code](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FittingData.html) for fitting **2D Gaussian** on the result of template matching my data is the result of template matching contain the value show quality of matching with the coordinate of `(x,y)`. 
After fitting `2D_Gaussian` as we can see in the following plot the best result is the dark blue circle. I want to extract this area as a form of the covariance matrix. I get the best match with this code:

```
_minVal, _maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result, None).
```

As you can see in the following image is **`(27, 40)`** with a value of **`0.82`**  which shows the quality of the match. How can I estimate the covariance matrix when I have the best point of the match with the surrounding area as we can see?
[image]

Comment: Preferably put the code snippet you tried in the question. Explain what you have tried and where you are stuck. Kindly look at [How to Ask link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).